# How to foreach check data and display horizontally?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The below is the sample set of my data:

```
ID    DATETIME    
1     29-12-2016 03:00
2     28-12-2016 14:00
3     28-12-2016 16:00
4     25-12-2016 00:00
```

Expected Result:

```
ID    DATETIME             24HoursDataExisted
1     29-12-2016 03:00     0
2     28-12-2016 14:00     1
3     28-12-2016 16:00     1
4     25-12-2016 00:00     0
```

How to write such query where for each record tell if there is another record existed within the next 24 hours? It has something to do with the `DATEADD(hh, 24,datetime)` but I'm not sure how to writing it down into SQL.

From the above sample data, ID2 record is true due to the record of ID1 and ID3 and ID3 is true because of ID1 record.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using 2012,you can use lead function..

```
select id,datetimee,
case  
when datediff(hour,convert(datetime,datetimee,105),cast(lead(convert(datetime,datetimee,105)) 
over (order by convert(datetime,datetimee,105)) as datetime))<=24 
then 1 else 0 end
from #temp
order by id desc
```

for 2008,you can use below

```
;with cte
as
(
select id,convert(datetime,datetimee,105) as dtval,
row_number() over (order by id desc) as rownum
from #temp
)
select c1.id,c1.dtval,
case when datediff(hour,c1.dtval,c2.dtval)<=25 then 1 else 0 end as comecol
 from cte c1
left join cte c2
on c1.rownum+1=c2.rownum
```

Output:

```
id  datetimee          somecol
4   25-12-2016 00:00    0
3   28-12-2016 16:00    1
2   28-12-2016 14:00    1
1   29-12-2016 15:00    0
```

Comment: Can you explain where the `datetimee` comes from?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the application is still running on SQL server 2008

Comment: @Twinkles:thats some dummy col based on user data